# In JSF,how to get parameter values form my sql to jsf the page?

Tags: sql, jsf

I first made a sql, zdsql, for this project：

```
create table zdsql(
  id integer primary key,   
  filter varchar(12),
  value varchar(12), 
  descri varchar(12),
  standard_number integer,                
  language varchar(12)
);

insert into zdsql values(1,'zdlj','1','1.rid',1,'en');
insert into zdsql values(2,'zdlj','2','2.ria',1,'en');
```

Next, I made the JSF, the following codes is the maining of my xhtml:

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{msgs.zdlj}" style="font-weight:bold" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="zdlj1" value="#{zsjBean.zdlj}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{zdsqlBean.zdsqls}" var="bll1"
           itemLabel="#{bll1.descri}" itemValue="#{bll1.value}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The follwing codes is the maining of zdsqlBean:

```
package bean;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;

import model.Zdsql;

import util.DBDAO;

public class ZdsqlBean {


private List<Zdsql> zdsqls;


public ZdsqlBean() {
    this.genzdljs();
}   


public List<Zdsql> getZdsqls() {
    System.out.println("zdsqls==");
    return zdsqls;
}

public void setZdsqls(List<Zdsql> zdsqls) {
    this.zdsqls = zdsqls;
}




public void genzdljs() {
    try {
        String queryString = "select m from Zdsql m where m.filter = :filter Order by m.id";
        TypedQuery<Zdsql> query = DBDAO.getEntityManager().createQuery(
                queryString, Zdsql.class);
        query.setParameter("filter", "zdlj");
        zdsqls = query.getResultList();

    } catch (Exception re) {
        DBDAO.log("genzdljs() failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
    }
}
```

However, I still don't get the right values. When I run this project, the selectonemenu has nothing, which should have two selectitems, the values should be same as sql.

Comment: Where you are calling `genzdljs()` function?

Comment: Presume that you have added ManagedBean mapping in `faces-config.xml` because you do not have any annotation for ManagedBean in `ZdsqlBean` class.

Comment: Check what @Polppan says. Appart from that, check that your `genzdljs` method is loading the values properly.

Comment: Why exactly do you think that this is a JSF problem? Are you implying that `zdsqls` is not empty after running `genzdljs()`? If it's actually empty, then that's not a JSF problem, but a JPA/SQL problem.

Comment: Thanks Polppan a lot! I add ManagedBean in faces-config.xml, then I get the right result! Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Polppan a lot! I add ManagedBean in faces-config.xml, then I get the right result! Thanks for everyone's help!

But I firstly used this website, could you tell me how to close the question and choose the best answer?

Comment: You are welcome. Here questions are not closed, it will be open for anyone to answer and make comments. So you have many choices to pick a correct answer. In order to choose a correct answer click the green tick below the up and down arrow on left side of each answer and you should upvote if answer satisfies your question.

Answer (score 1):

From comments, the problem is that you haven't configured the `ZdsqlBean` as managed bean. There are two ways to do this:

1. Add the configuration in faces-config.xml file:

   ```xml
   <managed-bean>
       <managed-bean-name>zdsqlBean</managed-bean-name>
       <managed-bean-class>bean.ZdsqlBean</managed-bean-class>
       <managed-bean-scope>none</managed-bean-scope>
   </managed-bean>
   ```
2. Since JSF 2, use the `@ManagedBean` annotation to decorate the class.

   ```
   @ManagedBean(name="zdsqlBean") //name is optional
   public class ZdsqlBean {
       //class definition
   }
   ```

This is covered in a decent JSF tutorial, you can find some in [StackOverflow JSF wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). If you're learning/reading JSF 1.x resources, **drop them** and go with JSF 2. Note that currently it's in version 2.2.